# ClamAV Error for scanning

Tags: pi-zero-w, software-installation, terminal, crash

I'm trying to install ClamAV on my pi zero. Which is an antivirus program.

I ran the command :

```
sudo apt install clamav
```

Then I typed in:

```
clamscan
```

But it said:

```
LibClamAV Error: cli_loaddbdir(): No supported database files found in /var/lib/clamav
ERROR: Can't open file or directory
```

So, the terminal installs it, but when I try to scan for viruses the terminal puts out an error code.  Then a few minutes later, my pi crashed. I have it working just fine on my 3b+, but why can't it work on the pi zero? Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You normally need to tell clam this is a new install using the `freshclam` command.

First create the file and dB directory

```
cp /usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf.sample /usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf
sudo nano /usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/clamav
```

Note in the editor set any preferences you want and change the paths on the above command to match your install location if different - normally I build from source rather than pull from the repo.

Then download the database and complete the config.

```
freshclam
```

Depending on what you set in the edit for the user etc, you may have to create a group and set security on the database etc.

Full documentation is to be found [here](https://www.clamav.net/documents/clam-antivirus-user-manual) and for Raspbian I would follow the Debian install.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it crashed?

Comment: My guess would be it tried to find files or run without being set up but without setting a box up it's a bit of a guess.